# Possible to forward Ethernet to WiFi network using a WiFi router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, ethernet

I have a router that I want to use to take Ethernet input and output a WiFi network, to make a kind of virtual network so that computers on the virtual network cannot access the computers on the main network. Is that possible?

Basic ASCII diagram:

Main WiFi > Raspberry Pi > Ethernet > Router > WiFi network with internet

Comment: Is there a reason for the complexity? Some other thing you are doing? This is commonly called a “guest” network on any home WiFi router.

Comment: @Appleoddity I just want a private network to play around on seperate from the main one and I dont want to pay for a second internet connection, and those are the materials I have

Comment: Wouldnt it be easier to just buy a router with a built in guest network?

Comment: @Ultrasonic54321: Many wireless routers simply attach both main and guest SSIDs to the _same_ subnet and enable "client isolation" on the 2nd one. So it's still the same "network", technically... and you can't even do much with it, because different clients are isolated even from each other.

Comment: The capabilities of the router are key; some can, some can't. What's the make and model of the router? Please get the model from the plate or sticker underneath or behind when the FCC approval seal is. Once you have that, please click on the `edit` link above at left, and add that to your original post. Adding to the original post is better than replying in Comments, for that way everyone sees the updated information all at once. And, if it won't do what you want, used routers are cheap.

Comment: @K7AAY WIll do, just got in bed :(